# How to use Static Resources for infowindow setContent?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am getting Image at google map when using image at marker, but when i am using same image for infowindow then it shows only url.

Code:

```
var content = '<div class="map-content"><h3>' + "Account Name: " + "{!acc.Name} " + 
  '</h3>' + '<b>' +"Location: " + "{!acc.BillingCity}"  + '</b>' + '</br>'  +        
  "Direction : " + '<a href="http://maps.google.com/?daddr=' + "{!acc.BillingCity}" +  
  '" target="_blank">Get Directions</a>' +  "{!$Resource.Image_GoogleMap}"  +'</div>';

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, this); 
                        infowindow.setContent(content);
                    });
```

How to use "{!$Resource.Image_GoogleMap}" to showing image at infowindow for google map.
can any one help me?

Comment: What is ``{!$Resource.Image_GoogleMap}``?

Comment: Thanks Joni for quick reply. Yes, this is URL of an Image and now its working fine and showing image at infowindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `{!$Resource.Image_GoogleMap}` is the URL of an image, and you want to display it in an InfoWindow, use [normal HTM](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)L:

```
<img src="{!$Resource.Image_GoogleMap}" alt="image description">
```

(be careful to match the ' and " correctly)

```
var content = '<div class="map-content"><h3>' + "Account Name: " + "{!acc.Name} " + 
'</h3>' + '<b>' +"Location: " + "{!acc.BillingCity}"  + '</b>' + '</br>'  +        
"Direction : " + '<a href="http://maps.google.com/?daddr=' + "{!acc.BillingCity}" +  
'" target="_blank">Get Directions</a>' +  '<img src="{!$Resource.Image_GoogleMap}" alt="image description">'  +'</div>';
```